# liquibase:diff sempre gera índices

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, liquibase

Estou usando spring-boot com o plugin liquibase-maven-plugin para gerar as alterações do banco de dados conforme as minhas classes, porém o comando "mvn compile liquibase:diff" sempre gera remoções e inclusões de índices e chaves estrangeiras mesmo que o banco esteja atualizado e não tenha nenhuma alteração nas classes (e consequentemente, não deveria ter nenhuma alteração no banco). Alguém tem alguma ideia se isto está certo ou como evitar?